# React, maintain the state of a component on history change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I created a React app, in which I defined the classic style with left-side menu, title, footer and main content.
In the side menu I then defined the navigation, listing the various items that compose it with the `<List>, <ListItem>, etc` components of the `@ material-ui` package.
Having therefore the main item of the menu, with the sub-items inside, by default I start that each main item is closed.
When I click on it it changes the status and then opens, showing the sub-items.
So when I click on a sub-entry I am redirected to the correct route via `history.push ()`.

However, I have the following problem.
Landed on the landing page, I would like to keep the state of the side menu so that it stays open, which is currently not the case.

Do you have any suggestions or advice? Did I do something wrong in the code or in the way to set the status?

- MY CODE:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import ListSubheader from '@material-ui/core/ListSubheader';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import Collapse from '@material-ui/core/Collapse';
import history from './../../history';
import SettingsApplicationsIcon from '@material-ui/icons/SettingsApplications';
import LocalLibraryIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LocalLibrary';
import ContactMailIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ContactMail';
import CreditCardIcon from '@material-ui/icons/CreditCard';
import VisibilityIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Visibility';
import DashboardIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Dashboard';
import ExpandLess from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandLess';
import ExpandMore from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';
import StarBorder from '@material-ui/icons/StarBorder';
import ListAlt from '@material-ui/icons/ListAlt';

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
    maxWidth: 360,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
  },
  nested: {
    paddingLeft: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
  },
});

class NestedList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    open1: false,
    open2: false,
    open3: false,
    open4: false,
    open5: false,
    open6: false,
  };

  handleClick(id) {
    if (id === 1) {
      this.setState(state => ({ open1: !state.open1 }));
    } else if (id === 2) {
      this.setState(state => ({ open2: !state.open2 }));
    } else if (id === 3) {
      this.setState(state => ({ open3: !state.open3 }));
    } else if (id === 4) {
      this.setState(state => ({ open4: !state.open4 }));
    } else if (id === 5) {
      this.setState(state => ({ open5: !state.open5 }));
    } else if (id === 6) {
      this.setState(state => ({ open6: !state.open6 }));
    }

  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const admin = 1;
    const url = window.location.pathname;
    
    if (admin === 1) {
      return (
        <List>
          <ListItem button selected={(url === '/dashboard') ? true : false} onClick={() => history.push('/dashboard')}>
            <ListItemIcon>
              <DashboardIcon />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary="Dashboard" />
          </ListItem>
          {/* prima voce del menu */}
          <ListItem button onClick={() => this.handleClick(1)}>
            <ListItemIcon>
              <SettingsApplicationsIcon />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary="Gestione" />
            {this.state.open1 ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
          </ListItem>
          <Collapse in={this.state.open1} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
            <List component="div" disablePadding>
            <ListItem button className={classes.nested} selected={(url === '/gestione/news_avvisi') ? true : false} onClick={() => history.push('/gestione/news_avvisi')}>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <StarBorder />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary="News / Avvisi" />
              </ListItem>
              <ListItem button className={classes.nested} selected={(url === '/gestione/modelli_email') ? true : false} onClick={() => history.push('/gestione/modelli_email')}>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <StarBorder />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary="Modelli email" />
              </ListItem>
              <ListItem button className={classes.nested} selected={(url === '/gestione/profilo') ? true : false} onClick={() => history.push('/gestione/profilo')}>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <StarBorder />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary="Gestione profilo" />
              </ListItem>
              <ListItem button className={classes.nested} selected={(url === '/gestione/ruoli') ? true : false} onClick={() => history.push('/gestione/ruoli')}>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <StarBorder />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary="Gestione ruoli" />
              </ListItem>
              <ListItem button className={classes.nested} selected={(url === '/gestione/cassetti') ? true : false} onClick={() => history.push('/gestione/cassetti')}>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <StarBorder />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary="Gestione cassetti" />
              </ListItem>
            </List>
          </Collapse>
          {/* seconda voce del menu */}
          <ListItem button onClick={() => this.handleClick(2)}>
            <ListItemIcon>
              <LocalLibraryIcon />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary="Anagrafiche" />
            {this.state.open2 ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
          </ListItem>
          <Collapse in={this.state.open2} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
            <List component="div" disablePadding>
              <ListItem button className={classes.nested} selected={(url === '/anagrafiche/utenti_censiti') ? true : false} onClick={() => history.push('/anagrafiche/utenti_censiti')}>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <StarBorder />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary="Utenti censiti" />
              </ListItem>
              <ListItem button className={classes.nested} selected={(url === '/anagrafiche/archivio_documenti') ? true : false} onClick={() => history.push('/anagrafiche/archivio_documenti')}>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <StarBorder />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary="Archivio documenti" />
              </ListItem>
              <ListItem button className={classes.nested} selected={(url === '/anagrafiche/archivio_rate') ? true : false} onClick={() => history.push('/anagrafiche/archivio_rate')}>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <StarBorder />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary="Archivio rate" />
              </ListItem>
              <ListItem button className={classes.nested} selected={(url === '/anagrafiche/accertamenti') ? true : false} onClick={() => history.push('/anagrafiche/accertamenti')}>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <StarBorder />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary="Accertamenti" />
              </ListItem>
            </List>
          </Collapse>
          {/* terza voce del menu */}
          <ListItem button onClick={() => this.handleClick(3)}>
            <ListItemIcon>
              <ContactMailIcon />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary="Richieste Utenti" />
            {this.state.open3 ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
          </ListItem>
          <Collapse in={this.state.open3} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
            <List component="div" disablePadding>
              <ListItem button className={classes.nested} selected={(url === '/richieste/assistenza_tecnica') ? true : false} onClick={() => history.push('/richieste/assistenza_tecnica')}>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <StarBorder />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary="Assistenza tecnica" />
              </ListItem>
              <ListItem button className={classes.nested} selected={(url === '/richieste/assistenza_tributaria') ? true : false} onClick={() => history.push('/richieste/assistenza_tributaria')}>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <StarBorder />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary="Assistenza tributaria" />
              </ListItem>
              <ListItem button className={classes.nested} selected={(url === '/richieste/variazioni_recapito') ? true : false} onClick={() => history.push('/richieste/variazioni_recapito')}>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <StarBorder />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary="Variazioni recapito" />
              </ListItem>
            </List>
          </Collapse>
          {/* quarta voce del menu */}
          <ListItem button onClick={() => this.handleClick(4)}>
            <ListItemIcon>
              <CreditCardIcon />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary="Versamenti" />
            {this.state.open4 ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
          </ListItem>
          <Collapse in={this.state.open4} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
            <List component="div" disablePadding>
              <ListItem button className={classes.nested} selected={(url === '/versamenti') ? true : false} onClick={() => history.push('/versamenti')}>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <StarBorder />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary="Versamenti" />
              </ListItem>
              <ListItem button className={classes.nested} selected={(url === '/versamenti/versamentiCC') ? true : false} onClick={() => history.push('/versamenti/versamentiCC')}>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <StarBorder />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary="Versamenti CC" />
              </ListItem>
              <ListItem button className={classes.nested} selected={(url === '/versamenti/versamentiF24') ? true : false} onClick={() => history.push('/versamenti/versamentiF24')}>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <StarBorder />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary="Versamenti F24" />
              </ListItem>
              <ListItem button className={classes.nested} selected={(url === '/versamenti/versamenti_pagoPA') ? true : false} onClick={() => history.push('/versamenti/versamenti_pagoPA')}>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <StarBorder />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary="Versamenti PagoPA" />
              </ListItem>
              <ListItem button className={classes.nested} selected={(url === '/versamenti/quietanzeF24') ? true : false} onClick={() => history.push('/versamenti/quietanzeF24')}>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <StarBorder />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary="Quietanze F24" />
              </ListItem>
              <ListItem button className={classes.nested} selected={(url === '/versamenti/parifica') ? true : false} onClick={() => history.push('/versamenti/parifica')}>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <StarBorder />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary="Parifica" />
              </ListItem>
              <ListItem button className={classes.nested} selected={(url === '/versamenti/upload_AdE') ? true : false} onClick={() => history.push('/versamenti/upload_AdE')}>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <StarBorder />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary="Upload modello AdE" />
              </ListItem>
            </List>
          </Collapse>
          {/* quinta voce del menu */}
          <ListItem button onClick={() => this.handleClick(5)}>
            <ListItemIcon>
              <VisibilityIcon />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary="Monitoraggio" />
            {this.state.open5 ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
          </ListItem>
          <Collapse in={this.state.open5} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
            <List component="div" disablePadding>
              <ListItem button className={classes.nested} selected={(url === '/monitoraggio/log') ? true : false} onClick={() => history.push('/monitoraggio/log')}>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <StarBorder />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary="Log" />
              </ListItem>
              <ListItem button className={classes.nested} selected={(url === '/monitoraggio/log_F24') ? true : false} onClick={() => history.push('/monitoraggio/log_F24')}>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <StarBorder />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary="Log F24" />
              </ListItem>
            </List>
          </Collapse>
          {/* sesta voce del menu */}
          <ListItem button onClick={() => this.handleClick(6)}>
            <ListItemIcon>
              <ListAlt />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary="Report IMU/TASI" />
            {this.state.open6 ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
          </ListItem>
          <Collapse in={this.state.open6} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
            <List component="div" disablePadding>
              <ListItem button className={classes.nested} selected={(url === '/imu_tasi/lista_immobili_imu_tasi') ? true : false} onClick={() => history.push('/imu_tasi/lista_immobili_imu_tasi')}>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <StarBorder />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary="Lista immobili" />
              </ListItem>
              <ListItem button className={classes.nested} selected={(url === '/imu_tasi/dettagli_modello_F24') ? true : false} onClick={() => history.push('/imu_tasi/dettagli_modello_F24')}>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <StarBorder />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary="Dettaglio F24" />
              </ListItem>
            </List>
          </Collapse>
        </List>);
    } else {
      return (
        <List>
          <ListItem button selected={(url === '') ? true : false} onClick={() => history.push('/dashboard')}>
            <ListItemIcon>
              <DashboardIcon />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary="Dashboard" />
          </ListItem>
        </List>
      );
    }

  }
}

NestedList.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(NestedList);
```

Answer (score 0):

State are by default not persistent. You can have a look into storing value in the local storage and retrieving the state saved.

Read more at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage